# Should we merge the tags [song-interpretation] and [meaning]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

The tag [meaning](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) has the following wiki excerpt (it has no wiki currently):

> What does a specific part of a song mean? What does the interpreter or songwriter try to tell us?

This makes the tag [song-interpretation](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-interpretation) redundant.

In fact, there are only 11 questions tagged [song-interpretation](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-interpretation), all of which are naturally within the scope of the tag [meaning](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning), which has 133 questions.

So, I suggest that we either retag the questions tagged [song-interpretation](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-interpretation) so that we can eliminate it, or synonymise and merge the tags keeping [meaning](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) as the master.

Comment: "So, I suggest that we retag the questions tagged [tag:song-interpretation] so that we can eliminate it." If we do that, it will eventually pop-up again. How about synonimizing the tags instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I vote for synonymising for the reason Mast mentioned in the comments.